# About the convective constancy of Clebsch potentials

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, vector-fields

For a fluid with non-zero vorticity, the following representation for the velocity in terms of scalar variables is well-known:
$$
\vec{v}=\vec{\nabla}\phi +\beta\vec{\nabla}{\gamma}
$$
It is called Clebsch representation. I've been reading that the so called Clebsch variables $\gamma$ and $\beta$ have a zero convective derivative:
$$
\dot{\gamma}+(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\gamma=0
$$
$$
\dot{\beta}+(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla})\beta=0
$$

Why do Clebsch variables have a zero convective derivative?

I've tried to prove it by myself but I haven't been able . I've been searching a lot for a proof trough the Internet, but the only things I've found require lagrangian or hamiltonian formalism. Can I prove these equations by only using Euler fluid equations and/or continuity equation?

Comment: Been reading where?

Comment: Hint. There is gauge freedom in the definition of these potentials. Can you use it to get *out* of  convective constancy?

Comment: @Qmechanic In [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.311&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, which Gauge freedom?